# How to write large random binary file with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, file, binary, fs

Wanting to write large binary files to disk using NodeJS but WriteStream.write is async and closing before file is written, resulting in an empty file.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I got to work.

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var fs = require('fs');
function writeFile(i) {
  const fileKey = Math.floor(Math.random()*2000*1000*500);
  var wstream = fs.createWriteStream(`myBinaryFile${fileKey}.dat`);
  // create another Buffer of 100 bytes and write
  const fileSize = Math.floor(Math.random()*2000*1000*500);
  console.log(`Writing ${Math.floor(fileSize/1000/1000)} MB to file ${i} with id ${fileKey}`)
  wstream.write(crypto.randomBytes(fileSize));
  wstream.end();
  wstream.on("finish", function() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      writeFile(i+1)
    }, 15000);
  });
}
writeFile(0);
setInterval(() => {}, 1000);
```